# Prolog on finding last element of a list with append

Tags: list, prolog, element

So i found a way of solving it from stackoverflow and it involves this answer:

```
last(X,Y) :-
    append(_,[X],Y).
```

But i can't actually understand how this actually works.
If anyone can help me it would be really helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`append/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) in several directions. You can for example pass a list, and look how two lists can append to that list. For example:

```
?- append(X, Y, [1,4,2,5]).
X = [],
Y = [1, 4, 2, 5] ;
X = [1],
Y = [4, 2, 5] ;
X = [1, 4],
Y = [2, 5] ;
X = [1, 4, 2],
Y = [5] ;
X = [1, 4, 2, 5],
Y = [] ;
false.
```

As you can see, there are five ways to construct that. For example with `X = []` and `Y = [1,4,2,5]`, or with `X = [1]` and `Y = [4,2,5]`.

We thus define the predicate `last/2` as:

```
last(X, L) :-
    append(_, [X], L).
```

Notice the `[X]` as second parameter. We here thus specify that the second list should be a *singleton* list (a list with *exactly* one element). An empty list, or a list with two or more elements will *not* unify with `[X]`.

The `append/3` predicate will this aim to unify the second list with candidates like we have seen in the example. But only if the second list is an singleton list, it will match, in which case `X` is unified with the last element.

Answer (score 0):

See the definition on the [SWI-Prolog website](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3).

One of the examples is:

```
?- append(X, [Last], [a,b,c]).
X = [a,b],
Last = c.
```

It means the Last is the single element in a list.

Think of the imperative way that `X` appends the "Last" to the end of the list. Then, it becomes the list [a,b,c].

Therefore, to define the last, we could:

```
mylast(Xs,Last):-
  append(_,[Last],Xs). % doesn't care about the rest of the elements except the [Last]
```